# Separate link in address line for single page different content

Tags: javascript, html

If I have two links in `index.php`  page:

```
 <li><a onclick="content1()"></a></li>   
 <li><a onclick="content2()"></a></li>
```

with different data to show on the same page:

```
function content1() {
   text.innerHTML = "text 1";
   ...
} 

function content2() {
   text.innerHTML = "text 2";
   ...
}
```

How to attach separate link name in browser address line and its different content  function call with using of this links in single page. If I'm not loading some separate page.html,  but get same result as with different pages:

```
www.mysite.org/cont1

www.mysite.org/cont2
```

Comment: Where is cont1 and cont2 comes from. Your question need more details and clarity to be answered properly.

Comment: What is `text.innerHTML` ? text for `li` or `a`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hello, seems like this actually is a question, so I want load different content with using of different tag in address line, which does not exists as page

Comment: @ AlwaysHelping "text" it is just example of different content attached to some   item for example <h2 id="text"></h2>; so this part implies different changes on the same page for separate functions. cont1 and cont2  is the desired address and function call through the required link on the same  page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLSearchParams`

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (urlParams.get(‘content’) == ‘cont1’) {
    content1();
}
else if (urlParams.get(‘content’) == ‘cont2’) {
    content2();
}
```

You’ll need to link like this:

```
www.mysite.org/?content=cont1
```